# Copy rows until the last row with value ONLY to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I was able to copy the rows to another workbook by using predefined ranges. However, I wanted to make sure that it only needs to copy those with values. I've been formulating this code but it returns an error -1004

```
Private Sub test()

Dim WBa As Workbook, MyPathA As String
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim getDBsht As Worksheet

MyPathA = "sharepoint.com/Financial Tracker v8.xlsx"  

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").UsedRange.ClearContents

' Attempt to open a sharepoint file
Set WBa = Workbooks.Open(MyPathA)
'Set WBb = Workbooks.Open(MyPathB)

Set getDBsht = WBa.Sheets("ConTracker_DB")
getDBsht.UsedRange.Copy

'error starts here
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").UsedRange.Paste


Application.CutCopyMode = False
WBa.Close

Set WBa = Nothing

End Sub
```

**UPDATED CODE:** UsedRange fixed my copy rows with value only, but pasting error still persists

Comment: `getDBsht.Range(FinalRow).Copy` copies only one row. Why not just `getDBsht.UsedRange.Copy`?

Comment: @Johanness that worked! thanks :) But the error still starts with the ThisWorkbook.Sheets block

Comment: There was an thing a while ago, that clearing content cleared also the pasting bin. So if the error refers to paste: try clearing the sheet first, then copy paste. Otherwise: are you sure, the sheet exists in ThisWorkbook (try a second workbook variable (like myActiveWB) set it in the beginning and explicitly use it for that command).

Comment: `Set myActiveWB = ActiveWorkbook`...

Comment: I get it now, the file cant clearcontent coz there's no content to clear. Would you know a code snippet to check first if worksheet is blank?

Comment: Actually, if you have a sheet "ConTracker_DB" that is empty. Used Range should be the cell "A1" and it should be possible to clear it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question :))

Basically if you're using `usedRange.Copy`

you should be pasting with 
`Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Please find below for the complete code if you're using this:

```
Private Sub test()

Dim WBa As Workbook, MyPathA As String
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim getDBsht As Worksheet

MyPathA = "sharepoint.com/Financial Tracker v8.xlsx"  

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").UsedRange.ClearContents

' Attempt to open a sharepoint file
Set WBa = Workbooks.Open(MyPathA)
'Set WBb = Workbooks.Open(MyPathB)

Set getDBsht = WBa.Sheets("ConTracker_DB")
getDBsht.UsedRange.Copy


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


Application.CutCopyMode = False
WBa.Close

Set WBa = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer. You should accept it - it removes the question from the "unanswered" ones.

Comment: couldn't have done it without you! :D Cheers! @Johanness

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the individual cells and copy only those which have a value:

```
Dim sourceCell as Range
Dim targetCell as Range
Set targetCell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").Range("A1").
For each sourceCell in Range("theNamedRangeYouWantToCopyFrom")
'I'm not sure if you need a dynamic range to copy from, but if you don't...
'...it's much easier to use a "named range" for that.
  If sourceCell.Value <> "" Then
    targetCell.Value = sourceCell.Value
    Set targetCell = targetCell.Offset(1,0)
  End If
Next sourceCell
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the final column you need copied and then defining the start and end cells in the range:

```
FinalCol = 23  '(or whatever you need)
getDBsht.Range(getDBsht.Cells(1, 1), getDBsht.Cells(FinalRow, FinalCol)).Copy
```

Also note that above I'm specifying which worksheet the cells  in the range come from. This can help if you have multiple workbooks/worksheets open at once.

Defining the destination before you start copying is a good idea, too.

```
CopyTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ConTracker_DB").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Hi @ebbishop you see the one I'm copying has multiple columns.. and I think I'm having a problem with the range. Should I define the pasting range as well?